# CSS color change on nav bar not working with class

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a button in a nav bar, when it's clicked it should be in the "active" class.  The nav bar starts out background-color transparent, when the button is clicked, the nav bar is suppose to change to background-color white (not working).  When I use !important in the .active it does work, but it is white before the button is clicked (no transparent).  These styles are in a media query.  Is there a better way to do this?

html...

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid no-transition">
    <div value="colorChange" class="topNav">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" value="hideMenu" class="navbar-toggle button_container collapsed" [ngClass]="{'active': !menuCollapsed}" (click)="toggleMenu()"> 
         <div>
           <mat-icon class="menuIcon">menu</mat-icon>
         </div>      
        </button>
      </div>       
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

SCSS...

```
    .topNav {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    }

   // adding !important to below turns it white, but no transparent before click

    .navbar-toggle.active, .topNav {
        background-color: white;
     }
```

Comment: On a side note, you shouldn't put a `div` inside a `button` as it's invalid HTML.

Comment: Thank you for that note.  Let me know if you have a suggestion (span did not work).

Comment: Why did `span` not work? This would be my suggestion, but you may need to style it with `display: block;`

Comment: Changing the color when clicked upon should work using the :active pseudo class.
Unsure if this will conflict with any other applied css. But based on the example above, removing the !important and updating your navbar-toggle selector to .navbar-toggle:active, .topNav {
        background-color: yellow;
     }
should bring you a step further to what you're looking for I think.

Comment: @IanDevlin Yes, thank you for that, display: block got the span to work.

Comment: You are very welcome @TMR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you want than when the button has a particular class, the parent component (navbar) will have a particular style. This is actually not possible with CSS, to affect parent components.
You should add the class modification to the parent instead, or maybe both, navbar+button

```
<nav class="navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid no-transition">
    <div value="colorChange" class="topNav" [ngClass]="{'active': !menuCollapsed}">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" value="hideMenu" class="navbar-toggle button_container collapsed" [ngClass]="{'active': !menuCollapsed}" (click)="toggleMenu()"> 
         <div>
           <mat-icon class="menuIcon">menu</mat-icon>
         </div>      
        </button>
      </div>       
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

```
 .topNav {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }

 .topNav.active {
   background-color: white;
 }
```

Or, becuase you are using SCSS, you might also use:

```
 .topNav {
   background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

   &.active {
      background-color: white;
   }
 }
```

Also, as a general rule, try to avoid !important in your CSS it is an easy solution for today but a pain for tomorrow

Comment: great . Wel explained

Comment: Yea, both of those do not work.  Thank you for pointing out this is not possible with CSS.  I will have to search for another solution.

Comment: I just realized than in both examples we are missing a `}` closing on ngClass

The third line should be:
`<div value="colorChange" class="topNav" [ngClass]="{'active': !menuCollapsed}">`

and the same for the button ngclass.
Try with the updates

Comment: @aitorpalomarescastellano.  Yes, this is working now.  Sorry about the missing bracket. I was able to get rid of !important by resolving a conflict in another media query.  I did not think about adding the ngClass to .topNav.  Great solution, thank you so much.